# Is it worthwhile learning PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

New developer using PHP/MySQL/Bash for scripts that automate processes, is it worth learning PDO.

Does it perform any faster?

Comment: Faster than what? mysql_? Not necessarily, but that's no reason not to learn it!

Answer (score 4):

1. Answer To first question: Yes it is worthwhile and recommended.
2. Answer to second question: Performs faster than? Its not just about speed, its about efficiency and security and better management aswell.

According to [PHP Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

> It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. It
>   is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development,
>   as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the
>   future. A detailed feature comparison matrix is provided below. The
>   overall performance of all three extensions is considered to be about
>   the same. Although the performance of the extension contributes only a
>   fraction of the total run time of a PHP web request. Often, the impact
>   is as low as 0.1%.

Benefits listed [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score -1):

It depends.

If you gonna use bare API calls in the application code, as almost everyone from Stackoverflow do, PDO is your choice, as it has some tools to make the process less toilsome.

But if you want to make some tool for running queries, to make your life **a lot easier**, I'd recommend mysqli instead, as it's being honest API without many unnecessary bells and whistles.

Comment: One always needs PHP - but not necessarily mysql